# Difference between addOnLayoutChangeListener and onLayout(changed)?

Tags: java, android

I have a class

```
public class FancyView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {
```

I need to get the height/width of the view.

(It could change with, say, device rotation.  Also, of course, the height/width is not known at initialization time.)

You can do this...

So, actually within the class `FancyView` just override `onLayout(changed)`

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    int hh = getHeight();
    Log.d("~", "Using onLayout(changed), height is known: " +hh);
}
```

Or, you can do this...

Again within the class `FancyView` use `addOnLayoutChangeListener`

```
private void init() {
    addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top,
                                   int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop,
                                   int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            Log.d("~", "Using addOnLayoutChangeListener, height is known: " +hh);
        }
    });

}
```

(Aside: I guess `init()` is the best place to do that.)

Both seem to work well.

Is there any actual difference between (A) adding a listener with `addOnLayoutChangeListener` and alternately (B) overriding `onLayout(boolean changed` ?

Use case: within the class `FancyView` I draw something on top of the image; so I need to know width/height what size to draw.

---

*Footnote. I've noticed wherever the issue is discussed "Android, get width/height of view" it is often suggested to use `onWindowFocusChanged` 9as it is "easier"). I really don't see why you'd do that when onLayout(changed) is available; perhaps I'm missing something.*

Comment: I would agree with you that the addOnLayoutChangeListener is the method to go. Because the purpose of the Listener is to inform an other process of the changed event.

Comment: hi @ZeusNet; thanks for that.  Say did you accidentally type the wrong thing there?  Since as you say the "listener" approach is for "other processes" - wouldn't it be best to just use onLayout(changed) here within the class??

Comment: Hi @joe-blow I think I would use the Listener for both. The intern and extern notification. But that is only my preference. The onLayout could also be used for this notoification but in my opinion it's better to use the listener to seperate the concerns

Comment: @ZeusNet understood and thanks a million for the thoughts! You may well be right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method `addOnLayoutChangeListener` is public so it allows to add an external change listener. OTOH `onLayout` is protected so it's only for internal use.

For internal use my understanding is that both methods provides the same result, but the override is a little cleaner.

Checking source code for [View](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java) I see that method using change listeners is

```
public void layout(int l, int t, int r, int b)
```

This method call internally `onLayout` and change listeners confirming that both methods are equivalent since they are triggered in the same way. If there is any situation where they are not called at the same time, it may be caused by a bug on the control implementation.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Yes, the override seems more sensible.  All the sample code I have seen adds a listener:  perhaps it's just one of those cases where: you get a "poor idea" in sample code, and it gets duplicated over and over??  Maybe onLayout(changed) is only recently available in Android??

Comment: @JoeBlow: added a edit. Checking source code for `View` seems to confirm that both methods are equivalent.

Comment: I'm wondering whether the additional Listener might be a little less efficient than simply overriding `onLayout()` since OP has a custom View anyway. But I have very little experience with custom Views so far. Do you think the Listener would have any relevant impact on performance?

Comment: @0X0nosugar: I don't think it has a relevant impact on performance but if you can override `onLayout` it seems an overuse to add a change listener.

Comment: sent bounty to say thanks for the great answer @ClaudioRedi, ciao !

Comment: @JoeBlow: ok, it wasn't necessary but appreciated nonetheles. thanks :)